# Stylesheet was not loaded because of wrong MIME type (text/html instead of text/css)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, mime-types

I'm currently developing a personal project that consists of a simple expense tracker web app. I chose node.js with Express for my backend, but I got stuck at the beginning of my journey because the stylesheet for the main page (index.html) doesn't want to load. I get the famous error: *The stylesheet http://localhost:8000/css/main.css/ was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.* I want to mention that static resources inside the public/ folder do get sent, for example I see my assets/ items on the page.
Here is the code inside my index.js file:

```js
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

import { compileSassAndSaveMultiple } from 'compile-sass';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // for delivering static resources
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // for working with forms
app.use(express.json()); // for parsing json data

await compileSassAndSaveMultiple({
  sassPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss/'),
  cssPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/'),
  files: ['main.scss'],
});

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

of HTML file that gets sent:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tracker App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b07dad4d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

And the app folder structure:

- node_modules/
- src/

  - public/

    - assets/
    - css/

      - main.css
        - scss/
      - main.scss

  - index.js

Any help would be appreciated!

I overlooked a lot of articles and stackoverflow posts approaching similar issue, but none of the solutions worked.

Comment: instead of doing `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` try only putting your directory name: `express.static('public')`

Comment: @KyloDev Nope, it didn't work, now neither of my static assets gets sent.

Comment: Is this not a setting on your server to serve the correct mime types

Comment: @Stefan Sorry forgot to note that you're gonna have to also change the route. `'/'` to `'/public'`. the css link's href will  now be `"public/css/main.css"`. it should hopefully be working now

Comment: Thank you for your help. I eventually solved the problem by changing the port on which the server was listening, from 8000 to 3000. I don't know what is the explanation to this, but now everything works fine.

Comment: welp.. that's a really strange behavior... What happens when you deploy the server somewhere else? Do you still get the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the port from 8000 to 3000.